# biweekly email through php on windows server

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I know it is possible to send email through php using mail(), however I wanted to know if it is possible for my server to send out a bi-weekly email automatically.

Simply, I want to get an email from my server with a bit of info every two weeks automatically.  Can this actually be done through php even if there are no visitors to the site for the two week period? If not, how would this be done?

I am currently using a hosted windows server using cPanel.

Comment: Yep, kick it off using a cron job. cPanel has a cron configuration system in its UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cron job to call a PHP script.

Here's an intro to setting up a cron job in CPanel - http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm, and your server would then execute your script bi-weekly.

Comment: had to wait another 5 minutes or so, you answered too quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

One rather hackish way to do it would be to set up a URL that, when hit, sends out the desired email. Then, on another server, set up a simple bash script to hit that URL and use a cron job to run that script at the desired interval.

Like I said, this is a rather hacky way to do it so there are likely better ways, but it's a simple and quick way to get things working.